# Which is a good and cheap 3D LIDAR or other options?

Tags: mobile-robot, slam, localization, mapping, autonomous-car

Our team is planning to go for European Rover Challenge (ERC) 2018 for which we are designing an Autonomous rover. In order to implement SLAM, we need a way of mapping (with a range of atleast 2-4 meters) for which we considered using a LIDAR or a stereo cam. Could anyone suggest a good, cheap and accurate enough LIDAR, Stereo cam or some other option by which we could achieve this?

Comment: Is it for indoor or outdoor? 2D or 3D? What is the required accuracy in 6 sigma range?

Comment: Both actually, terrain may not be very detailed. We need a 3D point cloud but if you think for the above mentioned purpose, a 2D one would be enough then please do tell us. An accuracy of about a cm or less would be good.

Comment: Your description is to broad.  If you can not afford LIDAR, consider using structured light.  BTW, is this ERC something to do w/automobiles?  Your specified distances sound more appropriate for small robots.

Comment: ERC is European Rover Challenge. By cheap I mean comparitively.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Abhishek Dinesan, but I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works, and the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for details of how to write a good question.

Answer (score 6):

There are now some sub and around ~1000USD 3D Lidars available. I wanted to provide an answer for future reference if anyone else comes looking for "cheap" Lidars.

- *LeddarTech M16 ~500 USD on Ebay*

  - Range: 110 m
  - FOV: 19x3.0 degrees (up to 8.0 degrees depending on model, with 30 m range at that FoV)
  - Refresh rate: 6.25 Hz
  - https://store.leddartech.com/
- *BeneWake CE30 ~1000 - 1500USD on ebay*

  - Range: 30 m
  - FoV: 60x4 degrees (up to 132x9 for 4 m range)
  - Refresh rate: 30Hz
  - http://en.benewake.com/product/detail/5c34571eadd0b639f4340ce5.html
- *Livox Mid40/Mid-100 ~600 - 1500USD*

  - Range: 90m
  - FoV: 38.4 circular (Mid-40 has a 38.4 circular pattern FoV, so its a bit special, but it can technically be used as a 3D lidar, however the pointcloud pattern is a bit different, the Mid-100 is 3 mid-40 providing up to 100 degree FoV)
    [image]
  - Refresh rate:
  - https://store.dji.com/product/livox-mid?vid=48991

A really good review on the Mid-40 can be found [here](https://msadowski.github.io/livox-mid40-review/). It also explains some of the challenges with the circular patterns, as some SLAM algorithms and fusing algorithms might needs to be adapted to this new pattern, thus not working out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

There is no cheap outdoor 3D LiDAR (as long as the definition of your "cheap" is under USD1000).

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AFH2yN3rM78) might suit your purpose. There are low cost (USD100~500) 2D LiDARs. You may need to combine camera and LiDAR if you need to cope with pattern-less scenes or dark scenes.

By the way, a good engineer should not use terms such as "good, cheap, accurate" without explanation. Try to quantify your requirements next time.

Comment: Will ZED cam or any stereo cam work for environments like say the ones at ERC, URC and all?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how wide your field of view needs to be, having two of [those cameras](http://shop-orbbec3d-com.3dcartstores.com/Astra-Mini_p_40.html) can provide pretty satisfactory results for indoor mapping with the range you mentioned. An Odroid XU4 board has enough power to compute the pointclouds for two of those cameras which you would relay to your main computer (using ROS) where the computation of the 3d map is done.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a cheap solid state Lidar for a Rover perhaps the Terabee TeraRanger Evo in the 8 x 60m configuration could work for you: [TeraRanger Tower](https://www.terabee.com/shop/lidar-tof-multi-directional-arrays/teraranger-tower-evo/)

This version can work outdoor within the range you are looking for and it costs €599 so about $ 670 usd